# UPDATE column using a result from SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns an error : "Subquery returns more than one row":

```
UPDATE forums as f 
SET f.f_last_pid = (SELECT pid FROM  posts ORDER BY  ptime DESC )
```

I know that i need to use `ANY` before the subquery but that won't get the proper result I want. I want to update every row in my forums table based on the result shown from the subquery.

Comment: This query doesn't make sense.  You want to update your forum.f_last_pid with one value?  Or multiple values?  Your sub-select returns multiple values, but you're storing it in a single value.  Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE forums as f 
SET f.f_last_pid = 
    (SELECT pid FROM posts ORDER BY ptime DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

But (without really knowing your schema), you're not joining these tables on anything. Every `last_pid` in `forums` would be updated by the last post in `posts`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE forums as f
SET f.f_last_pid = (SELECT pid FROM posts ORDER BY ptime DESC LIMIT 1)
```